# custom editingAccessoryView not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have the following code for a UITableView with custom cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FolderCellViewController"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FolderCellViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.editingAccessoryView=accessoryView; //accessoryView is a UIView within a UITableViewCell, and it is properly connected in IB
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    return cell;
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO; //YES here makes a red delete button appear when I swipe
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        // [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

But for some when I swipe nothing happens. I haven't done anything but this-is there anything else I need to do for this to work?

EDIT: Apparently what I did only sets the editing style for when the entire table is in edit mode, not when I swipe on each individual cell. So what I want to do is when I swipe on each cell, the custom accessoryView appears for that cell. But I'm not sure how to do that..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The editing accessory view is shown when the cell enters editing mode. It does seem a little bit too hard to actually get this working, but I have managed it:

To get this to show both when entering edit mode for the whole table, and when swiping an individual row, I have implemented the following in my UITableViewController subclass:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (editing)
        self.editingFromEditButton = YES;
    [super setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated];
    self.editingFromEditButton = NO;
    // Other code you may want at this point...
}
```

`editingFromEditButton` is a BOOL property of the subclass. This method is called when the standard "Edit" button is pressed. It is used in the following method which prevents the standard delete button showing:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.editingFromEditButton)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    // Otherwise, we are at swipe to delete
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

If the whole table view is being set to editing mode then each cell will also be sent the setEditing message. If we have swiped a single row, then we need to force that cell into editing mode, and then return the `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` style to prevent the standard delete button from appearing.

Then, to dismiss the custom editing accessory, you also need the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Cancel the delete button if we are in swipe to edit mode
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.editing && !self.editing)
    {
        [cell setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    // Your standard code for when the row really is selected...
}
```

Comment: If you change `[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditing:YES animated:YES];` to `[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditing:!cell.isEditing animated:YES];` you get the added bonus of swipe to dismiss, in the same way it works with the default delete button.