# UITableViewCell custom editingAccessoryView - not properly dismissed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have implemented a custom editing accessory view as described in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295834/custom-editingaccessoryview-not-working) question. For the most part it works very well, but I have noticed a small problem with it.

When I scroll or select another row in the table view, my custom editing accessory is not dismissed. With the standard editing accessory (the delete button), a touch anywhere else on the table is captured and used to remove the delete accessory view - you can see this yourself on the built in Notes application, for instance, or in any other place with a standard editing accessory view.

This must be because I am returning `UITableViewEditingStyleNone` when I am in swipe-to-delete mode. However, if I return any other mode then my custom editing accessory is not displayed.

How can I get back the functionality of the standard editing style, where a touch anywhere on the table view dismisses the editing accessory?

The cell is not subclassed, but it is loaded from a nib file with a custom layout. The editing accessory view is part of the nib file and connected via the editingAccessoryView outlet.

I have managed to halfway achieve the effect I want by storing the index path of a swipe-to-edited row and setting that cell out of editing mode if another row is selected or scrolling begins on the table. However, I'd like to do it properly.

Comment: @jrturtonI am getting the same issue.. i have refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295834/custom-editingaccessoryview-not-working?lq=1 . can you tell me the solution that what have you done changes in your code, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this, but sadly it requires additional legwork and isnt just as simple as setting a couple properties.

In my

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method I return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` so that my custom `editingAccessoryView` will show up.  In this method I also do this:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
if(self.editingPath)
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:editingPath] setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}

self.editingPath = indexPath;    
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells])
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

This disables scrolling, then stores the `indexPath` we swiped on for later use.  If you swipe another row, while editing a row, it will unedit the first row and edit the second row, which is how apple apps behave.  I also set the cell `selectionStyle` on all visible cells to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.  This reduces the blue flicker when the user selects another cell while your currently editing one.

Next we need to dismiss the `accessoryView` when another cell is tapped.  To do that we implement this method:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(self.editingPath)
{
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.editingPath];
    [c setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.editingPath = nil;
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells])
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    return nil;
}

return indexPath;
}
```

What this does is when someone is about to click on a cell, if we are editing then unedit that cell and return nothing.

also for

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I return `YES`, to enable editing on the cells I want the user to be able to delete.