# How to make swipe to delete button smaller on UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm stuck here for few days..

My TableViewCell's height is short. and I like it except swipe to delete button.

It's too big so that button mess my table... It's not beautiful.

please let me know how to resize the delete button on my tableview...

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell custom editingAccessoryView - not properly dismissed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699431/uitableviewcell-custom-editingaccessoryview-not-properly-dismissed)

Comment: Hii @Bright Lee. Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be more complex than originally stated, but uses most of what I was saying below.  Look at this StackOverflow Link.

[UITableViewCell custom editingAccessoryView - not properly dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699431/uitableviewcell-custom-editingaccessoryview-not-properly-dismissed)

You may be able to setup your own UIView and use the editingAccessoryView property.

In this view you would implement your own delete button (however you want it to look) and capture the delete button press yourself.

Comment: Hello, I ended up decide not to use it, but I will make it myself. Thanks very much for answering my question.