# How can you style the default delete button in objective-c ios5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I need to style the default delete button on a tableview cell in objective c, ios5. The general idea is the assumption that you can do something like this:

```
    UIImage *addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenButtonDark.png"];
    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height);

    [addButton setImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushAddItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *addBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton] ;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButtonItem;
```

The above code is called in the viewDidLoad method and overwrites the right button in the header. I assume there is something comparable for any button the system adds by default but I don't know how to access this particular one.

If I am failing to articulate this, the delete button I refer to is the one automatically generated with this code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //do something when someone hits delete
    }
}
```

If I need to clarify anything let me know. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sub classing the UITableView? It *might* work. You would have to discover which method calls `- tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` Anyway, why would want to delete a bullet proof vest?

Comment: No I haven't. It just seemed logical that one could access the default button in a similar way. ANyhow, I should hope you delete the bullet proof vest as it suggests you acquired it and no longer need it on your list.

Comment: You can't access that button (except to change the title). What you _can_ do is use your own editing accessory view for the cell, but you then have some additional work to do to make "edit mode" delete mode, and implement swipe-to-delete etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8021606/852828 for some links about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [iPhone UITableView - Delete Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104403/iphone-uitableview-delete-button), it should basically answer your question. In short you might need to subclass *UITableViewCell* and override the *-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state* and *-(void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state* and modify the button here.

Another alternative might be subclassing the *UITableViewCell* and implementing the delete button functionality yourself (recognize the swipe gesture, present the button and handle when it's pressed in a similar way the default method of *UITableView* delegate does).