# Custom UITableViewCell edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, uianimation

Can't figure out how to do `UITableViewCell` with custom mode with animation like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDxz.png)

make swipe on cell so `UIPickerView` will appear, like delete

I'm thinking I need to do in my controller in this method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    //add something here
}
```

or in my custom cell class:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

found answer [custom editingAccessoryView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295834/custom-editingaccessoryview-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add UIPickerView to your table cell as a subview

Comment: where i need to add uipickerview in - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the custom picker as subview and keep it hidden.when you start editing in the delegate method make the view show by setting hidden property to no

Answer (score -1):

When you are making cell to show in tableview in method `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` here you can add your `UIPickerview` according to your need to `UITableViewCell` like this-

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:pickerView];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: i want to animate uitableviewcell than you swipe cell from right to left and pickerView will appear with animation